# Sorting elements returns wrong results in Node.js (v10.9.0)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the following code to sort elements based on how often they occur in an array but it's not working in Node.js. I tried running this code from the console in the web inspector on both Safari and Chrome and it works fine there. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function textCount(text, items) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, length = items.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (items[i] == text) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

var array = ["one", "four", "two", "three", "four", "two", "four", "three", "four", "three"];
var sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {

  var value1 = textCount(a, array);
  var value2 = textCount(b, array);

  if (value1 < value2) return 1;
  if (value1 > value2) return -1;
  return 0;

});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

These are the results in Node.js. They are not in order.

```
[ 'four',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'four',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'three',
  'one' ]
```

It works as expected if I reverse the direction like this but I want it to sort the other way.

```
if(value1 < value2) return -1;
if(value1 > value2) return 1;
```

Comment: So, in Chrome, that code shows 4 "four", 3 "three", 2 "two", then 1 "one". Is that what you want? It's not quite explicit in your question what your expected output is.

Comment: My solution offers the correct answer now. It appears that the array being passed to textCount is mutated in NodeJS, whereas the browser is passing the original array.

Comment: I edited my response with the results I'm getting from Node.js. They are not being sorted correctly in Node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass in the original array in a sort function, it seems to be calculating the number of occurrences incorrectly in this implementation.

The reason it works in the browser is that the browser isn't mutating the array variable, whereas NodeJS does. If you pass a copy of the array value it should work as expected.

```js
 function textCount(text, items) {
      var count = 0;
      for (var i = 0, length = items.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (items[i] == text) {
          count++;
        }
      }
  
      return count;
    }

    var array = ["one", "four", "two", "three", "four", "two", "four", "three", "four", "three"];
    let arr = [...array]
    var sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {

      var value1 = textCount(a, arr);
      var value2 = textCount(b, arr);

      if (value1 < value2) return 1;
      if (value1 > value2) return -1;
      return 0;

    });

    console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: I've modified my answer. The issue is related to a modified array being passed into textCount. If an original copy of that is passed, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working in Node, but one way to fix it is to do the counts before the sort, then just get the pre-calculated count during the sort.

```js
var array = ["one", "four", "two", "three", "four", "two", "four", "three", "four", "three"];
var counts = array.reduce((agg, cur) => { agg[cur] = (agg[cur] || 0) + 1; return agg; }, {});
console.log(counts);
var sortByCount = array.sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a]);
console.log(sortByCount);
```

[Here is the same code running on an online Node REPL](https://repl.it/repls/IntelligentElectricSystemintegrator).

I'm using `reduce` here to create an object with each key being a unique entry in the array, and the value being the count of that entry in the array.

Then the `sort` just looks up the count for each item and does a simple subtraction operation to get the appropriate positive, negative, or zero value for sorting.

This also has the advantage of being faster, since it's not recalculating the counts for every two items in the array.